# How to pass arguments to DLL initialization (ex. when loaded via LoadLibrary)?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

How could one pass arguments to the initialization function of a DLL loaded via LoadLibrary? Is it possible at all? Without resorting to some kind of exported function or shared memory, that is.

Comment: Why would you want to?  Just require the caller to invoke some initialization method on your DLL.

Comment: Having a separate initialization function is generally also safer: there's  limits on what you're allowed to do in DllMain - as MSDN docs for DLL main put it, "To provide more complex initialization, create an initialization routine for the DLL." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885202.aspx). Ditto for uninitializing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way.

The easiest may be through environment variables. They can be set easily before calling `LoadLibray` with `setenv`, and then the DLL (in the same process) can retrieve them with `getenv`.

Comment: Any way better than env variables? It is kind of portable yeah, but I would like to think about shared memory perhaps. Something that doesn't involve leveraging strings.

Comment: There's no point here on using shared memory: both the executable and the dll run in the same process!

Comment: The only utility of shared memory, would be the *named* shared memory. This way, the dll could get the data that the executable has placed there. But named shared memory is not portable. Furthermore, *named* shared memory is somehow equivalent to memory mapped file. This leads to another way of sending the parameters: *a file*.

Comment: Assumptions about the memory addressing of the process are a really bad idea. You can't expect things to be loaded at a specific location, and using mmap (or similar facilities) for a fixed mapping might not be suitable. What if you don't want to write to disk? Hence why I said shared memory makes sense (as in IPC-like shared memory, named memory, or however you call it).

Comment: I guess there's a misunderstanding here. EITHER you want to use data of your program into the DLL, and there's no issue with memory addressing as your program and the DLL (loaded from this program) share the same address space (there's no assumption here: it is true). OR you want to access the same data in the DLL loaded from different programs (different processes), and that's another story. I've answered to the first. Your question did not mention various programs.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution: create a second DLL that only exposes a "setparam" and a "getparam" method, than use it in both the application (setparam)  and the dll's DllMain (getparam). In their basic form, the methods are implemented with static variables, but you can use more sophisticated technologies. This solution, although slightly more difficult, has some advantages:

- it doesn't use any "global" convention (except the name of the common DLL!)
- it doesn't consume possibly limited resources (e.g. environment variables)
- it's general: you can use the same DLL wherever you want.
- it may be made as powerful and complicated as you need: e.g. you can make it thread-safe  if required. It's only a matter of implementation.

Here's a minimal example:

```
// The "helper" DLL //
static int param;
void setparam(int v) { param = v; }
int getparam(void) { return param; }

// The application //
setparam(12345);
LoadLibrary("TheDLL.dll");

// The DLL to which you want to pass parameters //
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE h,DWORD re,LPVOID res)
{
int param;
  switch (re)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
     param = getparam();
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative means**

While I'm not quite sure if this falls under "shared memory" *(since you can also use this method to send data to DLLs loaded in separate processes, as well)*... You could allocate some memory at a specific address using `VirtualAllocEx`, pass in a struct containing all the data the DLL will need using `WriteProcessMemory`, then lock it with `VirtualLock` before loading the DLL.

Then in the DLL's entry point function, I would use `VirtualUnlock`, grab that data using `ReadProcessMemory`, then `VirtualFree` to clean up resources.

Although a bit choppy, this is especially useful if you have more than just a simple string to pass on.
Note that you must have read/write access in the target process for this to work.

**Example** (pseudo-code)

```
// YourApp.cpp

struct DataToSend {
    int myInt;
    char myStr[320];
};
DataToSend m_data = { 1337, "This is a test string...\0" };

// ...
PVOID remoteData = VirtualAllocEx( hTargetProcess, NULL, sizeof(m_data), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
WriteProcessMemory( hTargetProcess, remoteData, &m_data, sizeof(m_data), NULL );
VirtualLock( remoteData, sizeof(m_data) );
// Save the address (DWORD) of remoteData to the registry, to a local file, or using setenv as suggested in other answers here
```

```
// YourDll.cpp

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved )
{
    DataToSend m_data = {0};
    PVOID localData = /* address used in YourApp */ NULL;
    //...
    VirtualUnlock( localData, sizeof(m_data) );
    ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, localData, &m_data, sizeof(m_data), NULL );
    VirtualFree( localData, 0, MEM_RELEASE );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is "bad" and "ugly" but you can push arguments on to the stack with in-line ASM before you make your call and pop them back off in much the same way.  A very hack-ish solution, but it can work.  I only note it because it's POSSIBLE, not because it's a good way to do things.

Comment: How could that possibly work?  The DLL code has no idea how big the stack frames are between the `LoadLibrary` call and when `DllMain` actually gets called.

Comment: because if you're doing bad things, and you know you can't pass args directly, you can find the current frame base and look right below it.  say you're replacing a function and can't manipulate the api it uses, but you have to pass args somehow... so you pass an identifier that shouldn't happen passed where the current stack frame is and check if it's an identifier on function entry.  it's ugly and bad.  that's why i noted it was hacky.