# Can I run a DLL from an exe with parameters?

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to know if I can run a DLL  function from a exe?
(C++ if it's important)
 And If I can can I do it with parameters?
This isn't really code but the concept is the same

Run Calculator(time,0,int,max)

I would like to run something like that, using parameters to open up the dll in a certain way. Is it even possible?
Bonus Point for anyone who can give me an example in code :)

Comment: Yes you can, take a look at "late binding", or if you have a header and a lib you can use those. This question is too broad though to be addressed without code

Comment: Thank you! I will edit the question a bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to DLL initialization (ex. when loaded via LoadLibrary)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678357/how-to-pass-arguments-to-dll-initialization-ex-when-loaded-via-loadlibrary)

Comment: You can call a function in the dll - that's what they are for after all - that function can do whatever you like. Its hard to see exactly what your looking for.

Comment: Ahh so let's say I have a function in my dll that prints words on the screen, I can run it through the dll? With the function?

Comment: @BobParker: That is the main reason for DLLs, to have functions.

Comment: Why is this marked as unclear? This is very clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have just about any function you like in a DLL, and call it, just as you would call any library function. And have as many parameters as you like.